# Is there a way to UPDATE a MySQL v5.5 table with row numbers by group?

Tags: mysql

I only have version 5.5 of MySQL so the ROW_NUMBER() function does not exist. Using this as a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(recordID INT(3), row_number INT(6), netID INT(6), 
              var1 VARCHAR(5), var2 VARCHAR(5)) ;

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 1, 2388, "Bill",  "Smith"),
(2, 1, 2388, "Tom",   "Smith"),
(3, 1, 2388, "Pat",   "Smith"),
(4, 1, 2390, "Fred",  "Smith"),
(5, 1, 2390, "John",  "Smith"),
(6, 1, 2390, "Hal",   "Jone"),
(7, 1, 2399, "Deb",   "Jones"),
(8, 1, 2399, "Keith", "Mack");
```

I’ve written the following SELECT, it returns row_number as I need it but I have had no luck converting it to an UPDATE.

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @netID_no = netID 
          THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1
        END AS row_number, recordID,
    @netID_no:= netID netID, var1, var2
FROM
    test,
    (SELECT @netID_no:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
   WHERE netID <> 0
ORDER BY 
    netID ASC, recordID;
```

I tried to make the select a MySQL variable like this;

```
SET @mycode:=( SELECT … etc );
UPDATE NetLog SET row_number = (@mycode) WHERE netID = @netID_no;
```

But I get all sorts of ambiguous syntax errors.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here, would some please give me an example?

Comment: update your question and add  a porper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge The sample should be just fine. The result would be a count from 1 to the number of the group netId entries. The question seems clear to me, please tell me what the problem with it is. And exactly how should I "update my question"?

Comment: Please, if you can, tell us *why* you're stuck on such an old version. I'm sure you have a compelling reason. Please educate us: tell us your reason. Maybe your situation will point to ways for the rest of us to avoid your situation.

Comment: @O. Jones I have to work with what the service provider provides. In this case the best he has is v5.5.?, I'm a little afraid to ask him to upgrade because I don't know what that means to all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interpolate subqueries with a user-defined variable. Variables take the place of a scalar value only, not expressions or subqueries or identifiers or anything else. Only use a variable where you would otherwise use a *single* string or numeric literal.

Here's a solution:

```
SET @netid=0, @row_number=0;

UPDATE test
SET row_number = CASE netID
    WHEN @netID THEN @row_number:=@row_number+1
    ELSE ((@netID:=netID)-@netID) + (@row_number:=1)
    END
ORDER BY netID, recordID;
```

Result:

```
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| recordID | row_number | netID | var1  | var2  |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|        1 |          1 |  2388 | Bill  | Smith |
|        2 |          2 |  2388 | Tom   | Smith |
|        3 |          3 |  2388 | Pat   | Smith |
|        4 |          1 |  2390 | Fred  | Smith |
|        5 |          2 |  2390 | John  | Smith |
|        6 |          3 |  2390 | Hal   | Jone  |
|        7 |          1 |  2399 | Deb   | Jones |
|        8 |          2 |  2399 | Keith | Mack  |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm using a trick in `((@netID:=netID)-@netID)` because that assigns the `@netID` with the value in the current row's `netID` column. Then it subtracts that same value, thus the expression yields zero.

This is the kind of awkward trick you have to resort to. You'll be happier when you can upgrade to MySQL 8.0 and use window functions.

Comment: ...or just dispense with variables altogether

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
UPDATE test a 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.recordid
            , COUNT(*) n 
         FROM test x 
         JOIN test y 
           ON y.netid = x.netid 
          AND y.recordid <= x.recordid 
        GROUP 
           BY x.recordid
      ) b
     ON b.recordid = a.recordid
    SET a.row_number = b.n;
    
SELECT * FROM test;
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| recordID | row_number | netID | var1  | var2  |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|        1 |          1 |  2388 | Bill  | Smith |
|        2 |          2 |  2388 | Tom   | Smith |
|        3 |          3 |  2388 | Pat   | Smith |
|        4 |          1 |  2390 | Fred  | Smith |
|        5 |          2 |  2390 | John  | Smith |
|        6 |          3 |  2390 | Hal   | Jone  |
|        7 |          1 |  2399 | Deb   | Jones |
|        8 |          2 |  2399 | Keith | Mack  |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```